# How to move DOM to rootElement in directive (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which has its template but part of it should always be appended to $rootElement. So wherever user put this directive in app's html part of it must reside as the last child of $rootElement.

This is a special case for transclusion I guess but I wonder if someone has already been done anything like this.

Example - let's say I have my-modal-dialog directive and user wants to use two or more dialogs inside each other. So I'd have this html:

```
<my-modal-dialog id="dlg1">
  <div>...</div>
  <my-modal-dialog id="dlg1-1">
    ...
  </my-modal-dialog>
</my-modal-dialog>
```

But the resulting html should be like this:

```
<div ng-app>
  ...
  <div id="dlg1" class="modal">
  ...
  </div>
  <div id="dlg2" class="modal">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea of how this could be done?

Comment: any solutions on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use compile method for this. Here is an example in fiddler - http://jsfiddle.net/EyDPh/

```
myApp.directive("myModelDialog", function () {
return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        'value': '='
    },
    compile:function(element, attrs){
        var newElement = angular.element('<div id=' + attrs.id +  '> Your content is - ' + element.html() + '</div>');
        element.replaceWith(newElement);
    }
};
});
```

Comment: No, that's too easy, I have to link it to the scope. This only could be done with transclusion but in this case only part of template should be transcluded. Will work on this tomorrow...